# XPI extension with XPCOM

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, xpi

Does anybody knows how to make a XPI extension with XPCOM component? How can we install XPCOM component into Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension) gives a good overview with links to more detailed documentation for various sections.  It would be a good place to start.